# What language/technique should I use to add a game loop to a Ruby on Rails based webgame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a web game in Ruby on Rails that relies on a choose-your-own-adventure mechanic coupled with a time-waiting system (a la Zynga and the come back in 15m, 30m, 1hr, etc concept).

However, I need a game loop to run in the background to constantly run and check if the "quests" that players are waiting on are ready and if so, ping the user(email/smartphone push notification/whatever they want). I obviously need it to do more than just this, but this is the core functionality.

I don't want to throw this into a Rails controller because I don't need the game logic running on every single page view or for it to be hammered when tons of users are on, rather I just need a loop to run continuously (at a set interval) and handle all of the small tasks that will be necessary to run the backend of a multiplayer game.

What language/technique is best for this, or do I even need to leave my Ruby/Rails foundation at all?

EDIT: This game does not feature a "persistent" world and has no real need of persistent connections with clients. The game is spread out over many pages and it will feature some asynchronous functionality (a news 'ticker' at the top that has updates pushed to it, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a background worker of some sort. Heroku supports a scheduler that you can set to run every ten minutes; documentation is here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler?preview=1

Otherwise, a system like Resque ( https://github.com/defunkt/resque ) or DelayedJob ( https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job ) would be good plugins for handling periodic introspection without tying up your controllers.

Comment: I'm digging these two tools, thank you very much. I can't wait to play with them. And you know, I know about Heroku's worker dynos and schedule system -- I guess I was avoiding it because I'm already using Heroku for the app, with a web dyno, so there is no free worker dyno on top of the web dyno -- and I'd like to avoid paying 35$/mo just to learn/build!

Comment: @ChrisRiley: I don't think you need a background worker for Heroku's scheduler system. I know that I've got a free app running Hourly Cron for $3 a month and it doesn't have any background workers. A note on Heroku's support page indicates "Note that the the scheduler add-on will run one-off processes which will count toward your dyno-hours for the month." Heroku gives you 750 free hours, only 720 of which are used for your free web dyno - if you use less than an hour a day of actual processing time in your scheduler, you should still be covered free by Heroku's scheduling system.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you sir. I think I may still avoid Heroku's system if only to ensure that my app will run outside of Heroku. But the more I read about Resque and DJ, the more I realize that one of them will work.

Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

Check out either [PusherApp](http://pusher.com/) or [PrivatePub](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub)

My idea is that the player will conduct a movement, and then broadcast out (via pusher or private pub) to the other players that it is their turn.

Comment: I'm not sure that this would solve the problem I have, but these are useful tools and one of them will be very helpful, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check on page load or by JS request if the event is finished already. In example when you show page that inform your user about time to end process then you will update it with JA, when time come to 0.0s then refresh page or use AJAX and show info that process is finished. If user leave the page and return back you will know that he finished that process.

Comment: The logic MUST be server side, as all of the information is server side and I want to expose as little game logic and information to the client as possible. (Much fewer possibilities for players to hack/cheat/exploit, I think).

Comment: Yeah, but whata logic is in my post on user side? On user side is only timer that check to refresh or not, all task finishing tests are on server side, if it's not finished then you reload page and show timer once again.